# Wrap a HTML element under a certain condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to put a HTML element inside another wrapper class after certain a condition is met, and remove the wrapper class after that. How can I do it?

This is the original HTML:

```html
<div class="piece" id="piece_' + piece.name + '" style="width:' + (5 * width) + 'vw;height:' + (5 * width) + 'vw;display:none;z-index:0;">';
```

I want it to appear like this if a condition is met and again remove the piecewrapper after condition is false.

```html
<div class = 'pieceWrapper'>
  <div class="piece" id="piece_' + piece.name + '" style="width:' + (5 * width) + 'vw;height:' + (5 * width) + 'vw;display:none;z-index:0;">';
</div>
```

Comment: What condition and when is the condition changing? (event listener?) and where is your script?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/wrap & https://api.jquery.com/unwrap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)